# Loaded images aren't visible in ios Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm newbie to Ionic Framework, but I have already faced with a problem of images loading.

Here is I'm getting an object of images' urls from the server via get response

I can see the images' layout via chrome's tool "Check element", but I can't see them at all on the page, they are just not visible.

Maybe I need to load them in cache at first and then show them or smth?

So, here is the code:

Here is an app.js file:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}

if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});

})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

.state('main', {
url: "/main",
templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
controller: 'ImagesDashCtrl'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

});
```

That's a controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ImagesDashCtrl', function($scope, myImages) {

 $scope.images = [];

 $scope.loadImages = function() {

myImages.getDownloadedImages().then(function(images){
  $scope.images = images;
});
}

});
```

Here is the services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

 .factory('myImages', function($http) {

  var myDownloadedImages = [];

   return {

     getDownloadedImages: function() {

  return $http.get('http://www.test1.com').then(function(response) {
              myDownloadedImages = response.data;
              return myDownloadedImages;
          });

}
```

}
});

And in main.html just a simple ng-repeat from images and so on, also I use "ion-nav-view" in index.html

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It seems you never execute the `$scope.loadImages` function.

There are 2 ways of referencing the images

one way would be to download them manually and put them in an images folder within the ionic app, then you can simply reference to them like in any web application. (they are locally then)

the other one would be you reference them in the internet.
So you use the absolute url to the images and they are getting downloaded.

I would recommend the first way.

Comment: here I'm just getting an object of images' urls and than parse it and trying to load images

I use <ion-content ng-init="loadImages()"> in main.html

The problem is: html doesn't re-render at all I think

Comment: you can try wrapping the inside of the function in a $timeout function
with this, it will be added to the execution queue 
in short: it gets executed after the current render loop